# Are countable models constructible?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Suppose a first order set theory $S$ has a countable model. Does it follow that there is a countable ordinal $\alpha$ so that $L_\alpha$ in the constructible hierarchy is a model of $S$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the question in the text, the answer is no. Let $S$ consist of (1) a sufficient finite number of ZF axioms to provide an absolute (i.e., $\Delta_1$ in the Lévy hierarchy) definition of the constructible hierarchy and (2) the sentence formalizing $V\neq L$.

For the question in the title, asking only for a constructible model and not necessarily one of the form $L_\alpha$, the answer is yes if the theory itself is constructible, but not in general.

Comment: What about any first order S which does not extend ZFC? Will such an S have a model $L_\alpha$ for countable $\alpha$ if it has a countable model?

Comment: @FAB The $S$ in the first paragraph of my answer does not extend ZFC.

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't (2) invoke an extra axiom? –

Comment: Yes, $V\neq L$ is an axiom not in ZFC. But (1) is only part of ZFC. So the combination is not an extension of ZFC.

Comment: Ah, yes of course! :) What if (as is my real interest) S is ZFC minus the power set axiom, plus, for a countable ordinal $\gamma$, less than $\gamma$ applications of the power set operation?