# Countable $L_\alpha$ model for $S$ if $S$ has a countable well founded model?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Let $S$ be a proper fragment of $\mathit{ZFC}$, and let $S$ properly extend $\mathit{ZFC}^-$, i.e. $\mathit{ZFC}$ minus the power set axiom. Is there a countable ordinal $\alpha$ so that $L_\alpha$ is a model of $S$ if $S$ has a countable well founded model?

Comment: The negative nswer to your other question (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416884/are-countable-models-constructible) by Andreas Blass also answers this one in the negative.

Comment: @Ali Does it? The answer involves $V\ne L$, hence it is *not* a subtheory of ZFC.

Comment: There are no proper fragments of ZFC which properly extend the ZFC$^-$, since there is only one axiom difference between ZFC and ZFC$^-$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek you are right Emil. In the mean time Farmer has pointed out that the current formulation is defective.

Comment: It isn't provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Consider $T=\mathsf{ZFC}^-+(V=L)\to \mathsf{PowerSet}$. In $\mathsf{ZFC}$ we could construct a countable transitive model of $T$ by adding a Cohen real to a countable transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}^-$. However, any constructive model of $T$ is also a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ thus by 2-nd incompleteness theorem $\mathsf{ZFC}$ couldn't prove that there are constructive models of $T$. Therefore $\mathsf{ZFC}$ doesn't prove the implication "there is a countable transitive model of $T$" $\Rightarrow$ "there is a countable transitive constructive model of $T$".

Comment: @FarmerS At least for me the natural interpretation of the the term "fragment of $T$" is that it is a theory $U$ in the same language as $T$ such that $U$ as a set of theorems is contained in $T$ as a set of theorems.